# Change hibernate column count with spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Today I use that code to count a select in my DB

```
total = protocoloRepository.count(
                    Specifications.where(ProtocoloSpecification.withNumero(filtro.getNumero()))
                            .and(ProtocoloSpecification.withTipo(filtro.getTipoProtocolo()))
                            .and(ProtocoloSpecification.withAndamento(filtro.getAndamento()))
                            .and(ProtocoloSpecification.withNatureza(filtro.getNatureza()))
                            .and(ProtocoloSpecification.withCliente(filtro.getCliente()))
                            .and(ProtocoloSpecification.withDataBetween(filtro.getCampoData(), filtro.getDtInicial(), filtro.getDtFinal()))

                    );
            return total.intValue();
```

but this code generate this sql:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(protocolo0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        protocolo protocolo0_ 
    where
        (
            protocolo0_.tipo_protocolo_id in (
                ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?
            )
        ) 
        and (
            protocolo0_.data_protocolo between ? and ?
        )
```

So can I change that count(protocolo0_.id) to count(*), that simple change take me 8 seconds in my sql

Comment: do you have a not-null constraint on the `id` column? What database are you using? It might be much easier to make the database realize the statements are equivalent than changing the SQL statement. Of course, you can always just use a SQL statement directly.

Comment: I using postgresql and don't have any null it`s my primary key (serial in postgresql is an autoincrement field)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is no difference based on the context in use here.

In other words, `COUNT(identifier-column)` returns the number of rows where the specified column is not null.  For an identifier column, this is always true, so semantically that is identicial to using `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)`.

What is more important in this context is that `COUNT(identifier-column)` can often perform better and return a faster result than using `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(1)` because the b-tree index for the primary key always be consulted where-as the other variants may be slower because a full table scan may occur depending on your database platform.

Comment: But if I change the count(id) to count(*) my sql runs 8 seconds faster

Comment: I believe that might be related to something else and not the `id` vs `*`.  I'd suggest you run an explain plan and see what the differences are and adjust based on that instead on speculating.